# How to get a caller method name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdb, call

Frequently, the same method X gets called from different other methods A, B, C. Is it possible to get a name of the caller method (A, B, C) from inside method X? Most preferably would be GDB console command (during debug) but stuff with NSLog would also be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typing `bt` while inside the called function will help. This prints the backtrace of the called functions; the function just below the called function in the call hierarchy is the one that called it.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  factorial (n=10) at recursive.c:13
#1  0x0040135e in main () at recursive.c:9
```

Observe, here, that `main` called `factorial`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command [`backtrace`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html) in gdb to see the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you're at a breakpoint inside of method `X` you can use `where` to print out the stack, you  will be able to see where the call to `X` originated.

Answer (score 0):

Typedef NSLog to print the function name and add it at start and end of the method:

```
#define CustomLogEnter(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"Function entered %s  " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

Since you want an alternative to gdb and without using breakpoints, you can try the above, Also you can log the line number using `__LINE__`.